# Running a make target from expect

Tags: bash, expect, spawn

I have a make target and on running it expects a user input. I want to automate the process with expect but when I `spawn "make abc"` it keeps telling that `Couldn't execute "make abc". No such file or directory`.

My expect expect script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn "make abc"

expect "*[input] File name:*"
send "../regression/regression_lehs.ion"
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: A makefile which requires user input is flawed. Can you fix that instead?

Comment: @tripleee Actually it is a build system(not actually `make` but everything will be similar to `make` so posted the question as this). After running the target it asks for particular which particular file to run(as there are hundred of files), then particular target in that file(which again can be in 100's). so in a way asking for input is better as creating this number of targets is impossible.

Comment: It may be a context problem. Make sure to include the full pathname to your `make` binary. Also, if your `Makefile` is not in the current working directory you will have to call `make` using the `-f` parameter followed by the filename of the `Makefile`.

Answer (score 1):

`spawn` wants to see the program and any 
arguments as separate words, so

```
spawn make abc
```

not

```
spawn "make abc"
```

With the quotes, you are trying to run a program named "make abc" (with the space)